# Building two packages with different requirements from same source code using conda-build

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I am working on a project that uses Tensorflow. The requirement is to package my code as conda package using `conda-build`.

Tesnorflow is yet to have one package on conda that supports both cpu and gpu see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997291/why-anaconda-has-separate-packages-for-tensorflow-with-and-without-gpu-and-shou). Instead Tensorflow on conda is two packages one for CPU `tensorflow` and GPU `tensorflow-gpu`

This will force me to build two packages for my project for CPU and GPU. What is the neatest way to do that using `conda-build` without having to have two repos.

Is it possible to have multiple `meta.yaml` files to build from using `conda-build`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your recipe will be *almost* identical in the CPU and GPU cases, the intended solution for this use-case is to create a recipe with [build variants](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html).

For your use-case, you probably don't need to read through all of the documentation.  Here's a simple (but complete) example.

First, create `conda_build_config.yaml` in your recipe directory, and define a variable and list each of the possible values it can have.  This instructs conda-build to build your recipe TWICE -- once for each of the values you listed.

Also, that variable can be used in `meta.yaml`, within [selectors](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#conda-build-specific-jinja2-functions) and [jinja templates](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#templating-with-jinja).

In this silly example, we'll pretend our package should depend on EITHER `zlib` or `xz`, but not both.  We'll select between the two using a variable named `foo`.

```
recipe/
├── build.sh
├── conda_build_config.yaml
└── meta.yaml
```

```yaml
# recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
foo:
 - bar
 - baz
```

```
# recipe/meta.yaml
package:
  name: mypackage-{{ foo }}
  version: 0.1

requirements:
  run:
    - zlib  # [foo=='bar']
    - xz    # [foo=='baz']
```

Now try building the recipe:

```
conda build recipe
```

Notice that it builds both "variants". Near the end the output, it prints:

```
# If you want to upload package(s) to anaconda.org later, type:

anaconda upload /opt/miniconda/conda-bld/osx-64/package-bar-0.1-h11ff1f9_0.tar.bz2
anaconda upload /opt/miniconda/conda-bld/osx-64/package-baz-0.1-he38177a_0.tar.bz2
```

So in your case, use a variable to switch between the `cpu` and `gpu` versions of your package. In your recipe `requirements`, select the particular version of `tensorflow` you need using a selector as shown above.

Also note that the variable you defined in `conda_build_config.yaml` is available as an environment variable in `build.sh`, in case you need to run different build commands in each case.

```sh
# recipe/build.sh
echo "Now building variant: ${foo}"
```